# Special Characters Problem in Android

Tags: android

I am making an application which uses services. The data that service returns me is in Italian language and includes some speical characters like ŕ, ŷ, ś etc but when i get the data in String it has ' � ' <-- this type of character in place of the above chracter.

What could be the problem . Please guide Friends and how to solve it

Comment: Please show us the code where you read and parse the answer from the service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be two types of issue:

- **Reason1:** Sending and receiving unicode characters. To avoid this problem while sending data encode the data with `Base64` and after receving the data decode with `Base64`
- **Reason2:** The italina scripts maynot be supported by your IDE that you are using for developement better way is to create a text file write your data their and then open the file to see whether you receive actual data or not.

Comment: can u please share some code. altough your point is right. when i m receiving the code it does not decodes it in good way that is why i am getting some wrng characters

Comment: can you share your code so that i can modify little bit. first tell whether server is using Base64 encoding?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the same string by changing the Locale of your system to Italian.